# Making statements wait before being executed

Tags: c#, wpf

i have this code, which has an animation and some other statements (they are like resetting the TextBoxs and other UI Controls).
what is happening is that the animation is starting with the statements at he same time, it looks weird that the users sees that the text in the TextBoxs suddenly disappers, so i want these other statements to wait some time (the animation duration) before being executed.

```
//this is an Animation that takes me back to the home view
        switching = (Storyboard)this.FindResource("view_Copy1");
        switching.Begin();
        //I want these statments to wait until the animation is finished
        st1.Children.Clear();
        st2.Children.Clear();
        st3.Children.Clear();
        st4.Children.Clear();
        name.Text = lname.Text = fname.Text = mname.Text = sex.Text =
                bplace.Text = bday.Text = idcard.Text = socal.Text = region.Text = location.Text =
                telephone.Text = mobile1.Text = mobile2.Text = email1.Text = email2.Text =
                ctype.Text = cyear.Text = emergname1.Text = emergrelation1.Text = emergloc1.Text =
                emergphone1.Text = emergname2.Text = emergrelation2.Text = emergloc2.Text = emergphone2.Text = "";
        region.Items.Clear();
        New.IsEnabled = true;
        id = "";
        bt_del.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: you should add a tag for the UI framework you're using, e.g. winforms, wpf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Completed` event that you can use and on completion you execute your code.

```
switching.Begin();
switching.Completed += Storyboard_Completed;

...

private void Storyboard_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your code to execute after the animation completed.
}
```